# Why typeid on function is ok while sizeof is not

Tags: c++, function, syntax, sizeof, typeid

Was fooling around in C++ when discovered this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    using boost::core::demangle;

    cout 
        << demangle(typeid(void()).name()) << endl // ok so far
        << sizeof(void()) << endl; // error here: invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type
}
```

I cannot understand why I can get type_info of function type, but not the size of it.
Some context on how C++ sees functions might be helpful.

Comment: `void()` is a the type of a function returning nothing and taking no argument. You can't sizeof a function, that just makes no sense. You could sizeof a function pointer, though. That's be `void(*)()`

Comment: A function is not an object.

Comment: And what "size" do you think a function should have?

Comment: @lightness races in orbit: I have no idea, but since a function has a type, I assumed that it might have some size as well. Apparently functions are just "special" in this respect.

Comment: @Cynic: Just think about it. They contain no data. Where would a size come from? What would account for such a size?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: static variables?!. And since they're not objects, functions could have size 0. The **real** question: how could you portably **use** that knowledge? Defining the result isn't helpful otherwise.

Comment: @MSalters: Them having size 0 could make sense (it doesn't, but it could). As for static variables.... oh please!

Answer (score 6):

The main reason is simple: in C++, a function has a type, but it doesn't have a size.  Remember that the  size of something, in C++, is the number of bytes you have to add to a pointer to get to the next element in a table.  Since you can't put functions in a table, they have no size.

Answer (score 1):

> `[C++11: 5.3.3/1]:` The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized *type-id*. **The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type**, to an enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed before all its enumerators have been declared, to the parenthesized name of such types, or to an lvalue that designates a bit-field. `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are `1`. The result of `sizeof` applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined. *[..]*

It simply doesn't make sense; `sizeof` measures the space taken up in memory by a piece of data: a variable or a constant, with a value that you can read. But a function is not a piece of data, and it has no size.

The amount of memory taken by the program code itself, although the program *is* loaded into memory at runtime, is never considered by any language features within the program.

The fact that a function has a type is not relevant! The above quote also means that `sizeof(void)` is invalid.

Note, though:

> `[C++11: 5.3.3/3]:` The `sizeof` operator can be applied to a pointer to a function, but shall not be applied directly to a function.

…which is relevant, I guess, though not particularly interesting.